# Select distinct on foreign key, inner join another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, distinct

Basically what I want to do is, select the 3 last actions made from the user. But no duplicates on RelationId, and also innerjoin permissions just to make sure the user has permission still to make the same action.

The only thing I want from permission is RelationId.

By no duplicated I mean if there is two rows of Action with the same RelationId the one closes to the top ( Ordered by TimeStamp ) should be picked.

What I've came up with so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, p.RelationId
FROM [Action] [a]
INNER JOIN [Permission] p 
  ON ([p].[RelationId] = [a].[RelationId] 
  AND [p].[RelationType] = [a].[RelationType] 
  AND [p].[UserId] = [a].[UserId] 
  AND [p].[Deleted] = 0)
WHERE [a].[ActionType] = 'Clicked' 
AND [a].[RelationType] = 'Direct' 
AND [a].[UserId] = 5 
AND [a].[Deleted] = 0
ORDER BY [a].[TimeStamp] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
```

It need to use OFFSET X ROWS and FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY for paging

This doesn't work for some reason, because I get duplicates on RelationId.
No errors.

example data:

```
action (
    id            INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY,
    ActionType    VARCHAR(50)   not null,
    RelationId    INTEGER       ForeignKey,
    Deleted       Bit           not null,
    TimeStamp     DATE          not null,
    UserId        INTEGER       ForeignKey
);
```

Desired result: 3 last actions made by one user that has permissions for it distinct by RelationId.

Comment: Sample data *as a text table* and desired results would help.  Also an appropriate database tag should be added.

Comment: What do you mean as text table?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Define a duplicate. You have DISTINCT there and there should be no duplicates, provided a duplicate means all the column values are same.

Comment: It is defined in the first sentence, defined on RelationId, no duplicates on RelationID

Comment: No it can't be defined as such. You have columns from action. Action has timestamp, which likely doesn't have a duplicate row in itself.

Comment: Yes I know, but what I want to do is to not get duplicates of RelationId. As stated above

Comment: Then post that sample data and expected results @Charlie, so we can better understand your requirement(s). We only have you attempt and incomplete DDL at the moment. We need the DDl for your other table, and DML for the `INSERT` statements.

Comment: I can't do that because the data is non accessable and does not look like this IRL. The data I provided is just sample data that fits both situations. I don't understand what more info you need to understand what my goal is. It is pretty good described above. I want to select actions distinct on RelationId( no duplicates of RelationId) and also join in permission, with an inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by doing this. Don't know if its the best solution though.

```
SELECT [a].*, [p].[Id]
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [RelationId] ORDER BY [TimeStamp] DESC) AS row from [Action]) a
INNER JOIN [Permission] p ON ([ep].[RelationId] = [a].[RelationId] AND [p].[RelationType] = [a].[RelationType] AND [p].[UserId] = [a].[UserId] AND [p].[Deleted] = 0)
WHERE row = 1 AND [a].[ActionType] = 'Clicked' AND [a].[RelationType] = 'Direct' AND [a].[UserId] = 5 AND [a].[Deleted] = 0
ORDER BY [a].[TimeStamp] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

From your definition of last 3 per user (if last 3 then it can't be a single row per relationId):

```
with data as (
  SELECT *, 
  row_number() over (partition by relationId order by [timeStamp] desc) as rNo
  from action 
  where [ActionType] = 'Clicked' AND 
        [RelationType] = 'Direct' AND 
        [UserId] = 5 AND 
        [Deleted] = 0
)
select a.id,a.ActionType,a.RelationId,a.Deleted,a.TimeStamp,a.UserId,
       p.RelationId as pRelId
FROM [data] [a]
INNER JOIN [Permission] p ON ([p].[RelationId] = [a].[RelationId] AND [p].[RelationType] = [a].[RelationType] AND [p].[UserId] = [a].[UserId]) 
WHERE p.[Deleted] = 0 and a.rNo <= 3
ORDER BY [a].[TimeStamp] DESC;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if last 3 then it can't be a single row per relationId)?

Comment: @Charlie, isn't that obvious? If there are 3 last entries for the same relationId then it would count as 3 rows, not 1.

Comment: Yes that I understand. My question is if there is anyway to work around it. Like how distinct works.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it, you need for each Permission only the latest action, and from all these keep most recent three rows. Here:

```
select top 3 p.RelationId,top_action.*
from 
    [Permission] p
    cross apply
    (
        select top 1 *
        from [Action] [a]
        where 
            [p].[RelationId] = [a].[RelationId] AND [p].[RelationType] = [a].[RelationType] AND [p].[UserId] = [a].[UserId] 
            and [a].[ActionType] = 'Clicked' AND [a].[RelationType] = 'Direct' AND [a].[UserId] = 5 AND [a].[Deleted] = 0
        order by [a].[TimeStamp] DESC
    )top_action
where [p].[Deleted] = 0
order by top_action.[TimeStamp] DESC
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But what I want to accomplish is to SELECT the 3 last actions made by a  user and also check that he has permission for it. ( I did it by inner joining ). That works well. But what doesn't work well in my code is to select distinct by RelationId. That will say one row per RelationId. Also it needs to be fit for paging so OFFSET and FETCH NEXT is must ( I think ) dunno how to do it otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Distinct will always distinct all parameters. Selecting * will always differ.
You need to choose just one parameter to determine.

You can use group by, or simply make it in two steps using same select. Like this:

```
select * from Action where id in (
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
FROM [Action] [a]
INNER JOIN [Permission] p 
  ON ([p].[RelationId] = [a].[RelationId] 
  AND [p].[RelationType] = [a].[RelationType] 
  AND [p].[UserId] = [a].[UserId] 
  AND [p].[Deleted] = 0)
WHERE [a].[ActionType] = 'Clicked' 
AND [a].[RelationType] = 'Direct' 
AND [a].[UserId] = 5 
AND [a].[Deleted] = 0
ORDER BY [a].[TimeStamp] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
)
```